# Propositional logic: prove equivalence of inconsistent

Tags: propositional-calculus

Given $Γ$ is semantically inconsistent, need to prove: for all propositions $θ$, we have $Γ⊨θ$.

"$Γ$ is semantically inconsistent", then there is no truth assignment $A$ such that $A(Γ)=1$.

But the definition of entail states:

> A set of sentences $Δ$ logically entails a sentence $φ$ (written $Δ⊨φ$
>   ) if and only if every truth assignment that satisfies $Δ$ also
>   satisfies $φ$.

My question is: Since there is not truth assignment $A$ satisfies $A(Γ)=1$, how can we find a truth assignment satisfies $φ$?

Comment: Look up "Vacuously true".

Comment: "how can we find a truth assignment that satisfies $φ$ ?" But in order to assert that $\Gamma \nvDash \theta$ we have to find a truth assignment $A$ such that $A(\Gamma)=1$ **and** $A(\theta)=0$ and this is impossible, because "there is **no** truth assignment $A$ such that $A(Γ)=1$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find a truth-assignment that satisfies $\varphi$.  What you need to prove is that *if* a truth-assignment satisfies $\Gamma$, *then* it satisfies $\varphi$.  And to prove that, it suffices to point out that there is no truth-assignment that satisfies $\Gamma$: with the antecedent part false, the whole conditional is (vaciously) true.